# Rebus #26 awaits your meticulous dissection

Tags: wordplay, rebus

For folks who don't care much for dotting their i's and crossing their t's, this can be a stumbling block:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's

> The Devil is in the Details (D-tails)

Comment: You're spot on!